# Write text or HTML to file on disk

Tags: php

I want my PHP script to write a file to my directory.  What this would do is write a file called `hello.php`, `hello.txt`, or `hello.html` and put it in a specific directory.

The reason is so that when a user fills out their name and age on a form, it would generate a `.html` file that would be a basic outline, including theirname and age from the form data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `file_put_contents()`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
file_put_contents('hello.txt', 'Your name is user1544586.');
```

However, is there a reason you want to generate static HTML files?  It is generally better to store data in a database, and then generate pages on the fly with PHP.